# I can not implement notification by ruby(iOSapp)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode

I would like to implement notification.
Bat, I can not it.

I tried it

```
 $ ruby ~/notification.rb
```

but I get an error like this

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/grocer-0.7.1/lib/grocer/ssl_connection.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./notification.pem (Errno::ENOENT)
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/grocer-0.7.1/lib/grocer/ssl_connection.rb:32:in `connect'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/grocer-0.7.1/lib/grocer/connection.rb:29:in `connect'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/grocer-0.7.1/lib/grocer/connection.rb:55:in `with_connection'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/grocer-0.7.1/lib/grocer/connection.rb:23:in `write'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/grocer-0.7.1/lib/grocer/pusher.rb:8:in `push'
from ~/Desktop/notification/notification.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Is the code mistaken?

```
require 'grocer'

pusher = Grocer.pusher(
    certificate: "./notification.pem",
    passphrase: "*******",
    gateway: "gateway.push.apple.com",
    port: 2195,
    retries: 3
)

notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
    device_token: "***********",
    alert: "Hello from Grocer!",
    badge: 42,
    category: "a category",
    sound: "siren.aiff",
    expiry: Time.now + 60 * 60,
    identifier: 1234,
    content_available: true
)

pusher.push(notification)
```

pemfile, device_token and passphrase are not wrong.

Waiting for your answer.

Comment: You have to pass a file name to `ruby`. I believe it would be something like `ruby notification.rb`.

Comment: The error states: *"`~/notification` is a directory"*. You are trying to run ruby on a folder, not a file. If the file you are editing is, for example, located in `~/notification/my_code.rb`, then you need to run: `ruby ~/notification/my_code.rb`. Or, if you are already inside that folder, you can just run: `ruby my_code.rb`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot pass a file name. I was tray again. But, I can not. Why I cannot?  Please show Question. I change the question , because new error messages are very long, I can't write one comment.